# USB OTG Permission broadcast receiver always gives a false result when using Android 12

Tags: android, android-studio, android-12

Good Day

I am developing an Android App that communicates through USB with a CP2102 USB-TTL converter. When I plug the device in, I get the prompt to grant permission, and upon pressing OK the broadcast receiver gets called, but intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false) always gives a false result.

When I load the app to my Android 10 device, it works perfectly.

Registering Broad cast receiver:

```
IntentFilter attatchIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    IntentFilter detatchIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    IntentFilter permissionIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION");
    getContext().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, attatchIntentFilter);
    getContext().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, detatchIntentFilter);
    getContext().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, permissionIntentFilter);

    usbManager = (UsbManager)getContext().getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
    hashMap = new HashMap<String, UsbDevice>();
```

My Broadcast receiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED))
        {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Device Attached");

            int pendingFlags;

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31)
            {
                pendingFlags = PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
            }
            else
            {
                pendingFlags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
            }

            usbNameList = usb.getConnectedDeviceNameList();
            usbManufacturerList = usb.getConnectedDeviceManufacturerList();
            usbVendorList = usb.getConnectedDeviceVendorList();

            for(int i=0; i<usbNameList.size(); i++)
            {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "DEVICE: " + usbNameList.get(i) + usbVendorList.get(i) + usbManufacturerList.get(i));
            }

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, new Intent("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"), pendingFlags);
            UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            Log.d("DEBUG", "Connected Device: " + device.getDeviceName() + " " + device.getVendorId() + " " + device.getManufacturerName());

            if(device != null)
            {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Getting Permission");

                usbManager.requestPermission(device, pendingIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Device was NULL");
            }
        }
        else if(action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED))
        {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Device Detached");
        }
        else if(action.equals("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"))
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "WE GOT HERE: " + intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false));

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))
                {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Permission Granted");

                    if(usb.InitUSB(intent, 0))
                    {
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "USB Initialized");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("DBEUG", "USB Init Failed.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Permission Denied");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "BROADCAST RECEIVER: " + action.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.

From API 30 onwards you need to add PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE when creating a PendingIntent for the permission request. However, FLAG_IMMUTABLE somehow removes the booleanExtra when the broadcast received gets called. Just using FLAG_MUTABLE instead solved the problem.